# Plotting gigantic values + smaller values on the same Google Sheets chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, statistics

I'm trying to plot a chart that includes one data set in billions, another in millions, and a third in thousands.
What is the most efficient/elegant way to do this using google sheets without the larger data set making the smaller ones look invisible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this easier, **Insert > New sheet** where you can scale the population to billions and incidence figures to millions using these formulas:

```
={ Sheet1!A2:A }

=arrayformula( if( isnumber(Sheet1!B2:B), Sheet1!B2:B / 10^9, iferror(1/0) ) )

=arrayformula( if( isnumber(Sheet1!C2:C), Sheet1!C2:C / 10^6, iferror(1/0) ) )

={ Sheet1!D2:D }
```

Use two Y axes where the max value in the left axis differs from the max value in the right axis, like this:

[image: chart with two Y axes]

See the new '[Scaled data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ioj4r4NwsIac5GrMDxd0YtJ9Vqcs101SI38OmsmvdnM/edit#gid=970551402)' sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the data set that is in billions was still too large - and the smaller data sets were smothered.

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to scale the data and use two Y axes.

Comment: Thank you immensely, this 100% solves the problem. Scaling makes a lot of sense for this kind of data range. Appreciate it!

Comment: What a cold, cold community where a "thank you" is not allowed according to the rules!
I've "accepted" your answer as per the instructions. I will rebel in saying thanks again for taking the time to rebuild, and explain my table dilemma. Kindly, verve88.

Comment: Appreciate that @verve88. Stack Exchange is really a _wiki_ rather than a _discussion forum_. The expectation is that questions, and answers, will be read and used by many others in the months and years to come, hence the rules. Both the question and the answer may also get edited by others to make them more generally applicable.